# how to get hash values by position in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I want to get hash values by position like an array.

Example:
 `h = Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200]`

In this array when we call h[0], it returns first element in given array.

That same thing possible in hash? If it is, then how ?

Thanks in Advance,
Prasad.

Comment: Hash and Order don't go well togethr in Ruby, so you would better be using an array instead.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned above, depending on your use case, you can do this with:

```
  h.keys[0]
  h.values[0]
  h.to_a[0]
```

Since Ruby 1.9.1 `Hash` preserves the insertion order. If you need Ruby 1.8 compatibility `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash` is a good option.

Answer (score 5):

Well the position is something that is not very well defined in a hash as by definition it is an unordered set. Still if you insist of being able to do such a thing you can convert the hash to array and then proceed the way you know:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
=> {:b=>2, :a=>1}
irb(main):002:0> h.to_a
=> [[:b, 2], [:a, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend Hash to get what you need follows (ruby 1.9.x) :

```
class Hash
  def last                # first is already defined
    idx = self.keys.last
    [idx , self[idx]]
  end
  def array_index_of(n)   # returns nth data
    idx = self.keys[n]
    self[idx]
  end
end

h = {"a" => 100, "b" => 200}
h.first # ["a", 100]
h.last  # ["b", 200]

h.array_index_of(0) # => 100
h.array_index_of(1) # => 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this:

```
h.values[0]
# or
h.keys[0]
```

But the order of elements are undefined, maybe they are not in the order you would like to get them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements only by keys. Hash is a structure where there is no order, like in a set.

Comment: Not true since Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Hash values can only by accessed by keys as explained in other answers. The index property of arrays is not supported in hashes. If you want to use a ordered hash in ruby you can use ActiveSupport::OrderedHash, but i don't think you are looking for this feature.